# Why does input's size increase in CSS Grid layouts?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a few questions in the context of CSS grid with regard to `<input>` elements.

1. Why does the label's and input's size match the grid's row height and fills it in?
2. Why are the label and input elements displayed as `block` in CSS grid but as inline elements in a simple div?
3. Why is my attempt at overriding their display to be `inline` ignored by the browser?

Finally, there's an implicit "how can I fix this" question here.

Here is an example:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: purple;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4rem 4rem 1fr;
}

.wrapper > label {
  display: inline;
   grid-column: 2;
  background-color:green;
}
.wrapper > input[type=checkbox] {
   grid-column: 3;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: gray;
}

.wrapper > input[type=text] {
   grid-column: 4;
 outline: 2px solid yellow;
}

.simple {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.simple > label {
    height: 50px;
}


.wrapper2 {
  background-color: gray;
  display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: 100px;
    grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 8rem 8rem 1fr;
}

.wrapper2 > label {
   grid-column: 2;
  display: inline;
  background-color:green;
}
.wrapper2 > input[type=checkbox] {
   grid-column: 3;
  background-color:yellow;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.wrapper2 > input[type=text] {
   grid-column: 4;
  outline: 2px solid yellow;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <label for="cb">Long Label</label>
  <input id="cb" type="checkbox">
    <input id="t3" type="text">
</div>

<div class="simple">
  <label for="cb2">Long Label</label>
  <input id="cb2" type="checkbox">
  <input id="t2" type="text">
</div>
  
 <div class="wrapper2">
  <label for="cb3">Long Label</label>
  <input id="cb3" type="checkbox"> 
   <input id="t3" type="text"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **1. Why does the label's and input's size match the grid's row height and fills it in?**

Because height is `auto`, in CSS Grid `auto` is stretched. because of the default value `stretch` of the alignment properties `align-items` and `justify-content`, We can override this:

1. `align-items:flex-start` in the block axis *(vertically)*
2. `justify-content:flex-start` in the inline axis *(horizontally)*

```css
[grid] {
  background: orange;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
}

[grid]>div {
  background: red;
  height: auto;
}

[fix] {
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-items: flex-start;
}

[grid]>[notAuto] {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h4>align-items: stretch; justify-items: stretch; (default)</h4>
<div grid>
  <div>Text</div>
</div>

<h4>align-items: flex-start; justify-items: flex-start;</h4>
<div grid fix>
  <div>Text</div>
</div>


<h4>When width/height are specified (not auto)</h4>
<div grid>
  <div notAuto>Text</div>
</div>
```

*Note: we can override that behavior on specific elements using their `-self` counterpart `justify-self` `align-self` on the Grid items instead of the container*

---

> **2. Why are the label and input elements displayed as blocks in css grid but as inline elements in a simple div?**
>
> **3. Why is overriding their display to inline is ignored by the browser?**

The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-item-display) says:

> The `display` value of a grid item is `blockified`: if the specified display of an in-flow child of an element generating a grid container is an inline-level value, it computes to its block-level equivalent.